# Expand trigonometric functions to their inverses in the complex field

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

How can you expand arcsine, arccosine, and arctangent to accept complex/transcendental numbers as inputs? (ex. $\sin(x) = \pi$)

I reorganized Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i \sin(x)$ into the form:

$\sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix} -e^{-ix}}{2i}$,

which is the standard expansion of sine into the complex numbers, and then I tried to solve for $\sin(x) = \pi$:

$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=2\pi x$.

Multiply both sides by $e^{ix}$ and moves all parts to one side:

$(e^{ix})^2 - 2\pi ie^{ix} - 1 = 0$

Then, solve for $e^{ix}$ and $x$:

$e^{ix} = i(\pi \pm \sqrt{\pi^2 - 1})$ and $x = -i \ln|i(\pi \pm \sqrt{\pi^2 - 1})| $

But, how can you simplify this into a generalized form for arcsine, arccosine, and arctangent?

Comment: You seem to have already answered your own question, at least the way it is posed in the title of the post. If you understand the exponential function for the complex numbers, then sine and cosine are defined by the formulas you mentioned: $\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2i} (e^{ix}-e^{-ix})$, and similarly for cosine. But then in the rest of your post, you seem to set this expression equal to something and try to solve for $x$. So is your question really how to find expressions for $\sin^{-1}(x)$ in the complex numbers?

Comment: I guess I do seem to contradict myself I'm looking for $sin^{-1}(x)$ instead, thanks for the clarifaction